# Git with daily production deployment

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, gitlab, continuous-deployment

There is a requirement by the customer to have daily production deployments with features that were scheduled a day ago. I wanna introduce code reviews but I am not sure were to start.

They use Git as SCM.

Currently there are 3 branches:

- `master` - represents the development machine and internal tests
- `test` - customer test
- `prod` - well...production

If there should be a change (doesn't matter what, feature, change, bugfix ...) the "workflow" is the following:

- new (feature-)branch (`A`) from production
- writes some code and commits into `A`
- merges `A` into master
- develop tests `A`
- internal QA notices a bug
- new commit in `A` and merge into `master`
- QA says its okay
- merges `A` into `test`
- customer says it's okay
- customer says it should go live tomorrow
- one admin and 1 - 2 devs are merging that feature(s) into `prod`
- deployment starts with the production branch

Assuming that happens in parallel and with at least 2 features in parallel development that can cause a lot of pain.

- no reproduceable builds
- on every stage is a different state
- merge conflicts in `prod`
- and many more things I don't even think of yet

So my question is: What could be a good branching structure where daily production deployments of specific feature(s) is possible?

Currently it's easy to see: it's a pure mess. You don't have to name it. :D

By the way, they merge, they do never rebase a change.

If it is relevant we use GitLab Community Edition and deploy via a Jenkins job.

Answer (score 1):

Re "*no reproduceable builds*": If you [tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) your commits, builds based on those tags *are* reproducible.

Tags also help to avoid multiple branches:

```
           P1                                          P2     P3
master ----o-------------------------------------------o------o
            \                                         /      /
          A  +------o-----------o----------o---------o      /
              \ A-QA1(bug)  A-QA2(OK)  A-C1(bug)  A-C2(OK) /
               \                                          /
             B  +-------o-----------o----------o---------o
                    B-QA1(bug)  B-QA2(OK)  B-C1(bug)  B-C2(OK)
```

Tags:

P1 .... latest production deployment, *new (feature-)branch from production*
QA1 ... *develop tests*, *internal QA notices a bug*
QA2 ... *new commit in <branch>*, *QA says it's okay*
C1 .... customer says it's *not* OK
C2 .... *customer says it's okay*
P2..n .... new production deployment(s)

Re "*on every stage is a different state*": There's just one state that's the point of reference at any given point in time and it's on *master*.

Re "*merge conflicts in prod*": There is *no* merge conflict from `P1` to `P2`. Merge conflicts are not prevented from `P2` to `P3`, of course, but not spread across multiple branches, at least.